# Attach a pdf file in-app-mail

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email, ios5, xcode4.2

I tried to attach my pdf to an in-app-mail. The in-app-mail displays an icon with the pdf but it doesn't send it. I don't know why...

Here's the code:

```
- (void)openInEmail {

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

        MFMailComposeViewController *viewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        viewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [viewController setSubject:@"Stundenplan 1A"];

        NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
        NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Stundenplan_1A.pdf", docDirectory];

        NSMutableData *data=[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

        [viewController addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"text/pdf" fileName:@"Stundenplan_1A.pdf"];

        [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: One thing to note, that the mimeType for PDF is application/pdf, not text/pdf. That could be the problem.

Comment: are you sure of the naming convention ?I mean is the name matching with the PDF file ?

Comment: yes i double-checked everything, I really have no idea why it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with?

```
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFileComponent:@"%@/Stundenplan_1A.pdf"];
```

instead of

```
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Stundenplan_1A.pdf", docDirectory];
```

And instead of NSMutableData you could tried it with NSData

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];
```

Comment: I was about to say use "NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Stundenplan_1A" ofType:@"pdf"];" but it returns the exact same as what he has.

Answer (score 0):

Change the mime type like this.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:pdfURL];
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[mailComposeView addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"CheckList.pdf"];
```

Comment: still not working, If I send the mail to myself I get an empty email

Comment: It works now with that code:   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Stundenplan_1A" ofType:@"pdf"];
        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: path];
        
        [viewController addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"Stundenplan_1A.pdf"];

Comment: yeah, I also though about your pdf location. NSLog the path, may be you are not getting path properly. File does not contain there. whatever, you solved it!!