# How to attach a PDF file to mail and send mail in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

Currently I am developing an expense management app and I want to attach a PDF file to the mail and send it to the specified email Address. So guide me from where should I start this and how to develop it.

Thanks.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *vc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
vc.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[vc setSubject:@"Monthly Expense Report"];
[vc addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",[arrOfExpenseDate objectAtIndex:1]]];
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: why do you instantiate the `MFMailComposeViewController` class _before_ you are sure you could send an email from the device? that is the reason exactly why the `canSendMail` is a _class_ method not an _instance_ one, you should not waste resources like this...

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101262/attach-a-pdf-file-in-app-mail?rq=1) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423158/how-to-attached-pdf-to-email?rq=1) may help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a example for you on how to send an pdf attachment using MFMailComposeViewController. Following is the code :

```
@interface ViewController () <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)compseEmail:(id)sender
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *vc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        vc.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [vc setSubject:@"Monthly Expense Report"];


        NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ApacheInstallationSteps" ofType:@"pdf"];
        NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath];
        [vc addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"ApacheInstallationSteps.pdf"];

        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert!!!" message:@"Your device can't send emails." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [errorAlert show];
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Result: canceled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Result: saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Result: sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Result: failed");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Result: not sent");
            break;
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Make sure that you add MessageUI.framework. Following is the output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To send a pdf or any other attahcment in mail using `MFMailComposeViewController`, you have to use:

```
[mc addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:mimeType fileName:filename];
```

For more details, follow [this](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-create-email-attachment/) tutorial.

You can also download the sample code given in this tutorial for better understanding.

Hope that helps.